# jquery modal dialog positioning at scrollable window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My page consists of bulk of data which I have to scroll down to the bottom for button click which will fire the jquery modal dialog. On the button click i had set the windowscroll position to top of the page and hidden the window scrollbar. But I am unable to position the modal dialog to the center position of the window, but positioned to the center of the document.

I have given the code like below :

```
$(settings.dialogDivId).dialog({
        open: function () {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            $('body').css({ 'overflow': 'hidden', 'height': '100%' });

        },
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        position: ['center', 'center'],
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $('body').css({ 'overflow': 'inherit', 'height': 'auto' });
                postbackCtrl.attr("data-validation-override", true);
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                postbackCtrl.click();
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                postbackCtrl.attr("data-validation-override", false);
                $(this).dialog("close");
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                $('body').css({ 'overflow': 'inherit', 'height': 'auto' });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have updated the code. here i have given the position as ['center','center'] which will work fine for pages with no scroll bar ie less amount of data but for bulk of data ie with scroll bar, the modal dialog is not centered to the screen. but it might be centered to the document.

Answer (score 1):

Place your modal dialog with `position : relative` if you want it to be centered in relation to its parent or `fixed` for it to be put in relation to the window.

After playing with `left` and `margin-left` :

If your modal `width: 200px`, you have to place your modal `left : 50%` and put a `margin-left:-100px`. Now, your modal dialog is centered horizontally.

http://jsfiddle.net/ArxAG/17/

Comment: I tried. Still not working. Currently my page works fine if there is no scroll bar ie less data. But in page with bulk of data it wont.

Comment: I have updated the code. here i have given the position as ['center','center'] which will work fine for pages with no scroll bar ie less amount of data but for bulk of data ie with scroll bar, the modal dialog is not centered to the screen. but it might be centered to the document.